# Python script to Invoke *.ps1 in windows operating system

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I am running a Python script in my laptop(windows 64 bit) but I want to invoke a windows powershell script to perform some task. This *.ps1 file should be invoked whenever I run this Python script on my windows laptop. Any ideas how do i do that? or what is the command to Invoke *.ps1 from a python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe [your command]')
```

or use the os module

```
import os
os.system('powershell.exe [your command]')
```

The powershell process has several command line arguments, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Thank you that worked: but how do i open in new window

Comment: Popen with creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE should do the trick…

Comment: Thanks Peter. Could you give me complete code that has Popen  with creation flags. I have spent some time trying this out.. but could not find the code working.